# Can anyone explain this sentence meaning in simple English?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

Sentence is **AngularJS is what
HTML would have been had it been designed for building web applications.**

What this sentence try to explain? and what is the use of **have been had it been** in this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is trying to say,

HTML wasn't designed to be used for building web applications. If it had been designed to be used for building web applications it would be more like AngularJS.

Comment: Note that the wording is mildly sarcastic.  HTML was/is a very poor design, "stolen" from a document markup language without careful consideration, and extended well past the point of reason as new features were crammed into it.  (Not that AngularJS is the epitome of an elegant design.)

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly old-fashioned syntax. It just means:

> AngularJS is what HTML would have been, if it had been designed for building web applications.